# Discord bot doesn't respond to interaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try kicking someone from an account that has no kick permissions, the bot says "the application did not respond".
The code I'm using:

```
@bot.slash_command(description = "Kickar alguém", guild_ids=[1041057700823449682])
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@option("member",description = "Seleciona o membro")
@option("reason",description = "O motivo do kick (podes deixar vazio)")
async def kick(
    ctx, 
    member: discord.Member,
    reason=None):
    if reason==None:
      reason="és idiota"
    await ctx.respond(f"Kickaste {member} com sucesso :)")
    await member.send(f'Foste kickado de {ctx.guild} porque {reason}.')
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.respond("Desculpa {ctx.message.author}, não tens permissões para isso!")
```

Kicking someone from an account with these permissions works well, but when I try from an account without perms, the bot doesn't respond with "Sorry user, you dont have perms".

Comment: Well the line ```@has_permissions(kick_members=True)``` makes that, right?

Comment: What happens if I remove that line? I'm not currently at my computer to test it.

Comment: This isn't discord.py, `@X.slash_command` doesn't exist, and neither does `ctx.respond`. Consider adding the appropriate tags & title to your question.

Comment: Jack142 please try removing the line

Comment: stijndcl, my bad. I also use Discord.ext. And Clement Genninasca, I currently don't have access to my computer. I'll comment again when I get access to it.

Comment: Clement, I removed the line and I managed to kick my own account (that has no permissions) from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by going into Discord > Server Configs > Integrations > The Bot, and then modifying who can use the commands. Also I removed @kick.error and the code with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the `ctx.respond` method actually takes an argument if it's a slash command. What you have is very close, but the correct code would be as follows

```
await ctx.respond(content="Hello world!")
```

You simply need to specify the content (does not apply if it's an embed)